# Add a UITabBarItem to an already existing UITabBar (made in storyboard)

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

So I need to add a new `UITabBarItem` to my existing `UITabBar` that was created in storyboard.

So far I think I've been able to access the `UITabBar` appropriately, but am not able to create the `UITabBarItem` and add it to the `UITabBar`.

So far here is what I've got:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    var tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as UITabBarController
    var tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar as UITabBar

    var tabBarItem1 = tabBar.items![0] as UITabBarItem
    var tabBarItem2 = tabBar.items![1] as UITabBarItem
    var tabBarItem3 = tabBar.items![2] as UITabBarItem

    tabBarItem1.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "tab-frame-on")
    tabBarItem2.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "tab-quote-on")
    tabBarItem3.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "tab-hash-on")

    var instaTab: UITabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "", image: UIImage(named: "tab-instagram-off"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "tab-instagram-on"))
    tabBar.items?.append(instaTab)

    return true
```

}

This function is part of the `AppDelegate`. As you can see at line 14 and on I'm creating the `UITabBarItem` like so: `var instaTab: UITabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "", image: UIImage(named: "tab-instagram-off"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "tab-instagram-on"))` and then attempting to add it to the prexisting tabbar items by appending it. This gives me a SIGABRT error on the `AppDelegate` class instantiation.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And if you look at the Xcode console it should tell what you did wrong.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: **'Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'**

`tabBar.items` is controlled by the `UITabBarController`. You must modify the `viewControllers` property of the UITabBarController instead.

e.g.:

```
tabBarItem3.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "tab-hash-on")


let instaViewController = UIViewController()
instaViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "", image: UIImage(named: "tab-instagram-off"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "tab-instagram-on"))

var viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers!
viewControllers.append(instaViewController)
tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers


return true
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! As a lesson that you very clearly pointed out - I will pay more attention to the Xcode console! Also, why exactly are we not allowed to directly modify a tab bar?